# Is there a way to start a functionname with a digit in PHP?

Tags: php, function

I am loading a lot of shop-data via XML feeds, and some of them require some preprocessing. I implemended this by calling a function based on the name of the shop:

`function [shopidentifier]_functionality() {`
e.g. 
`function amazon_functionality() {`

The problem I am facing now: there is a shopname that starts with a '3', something like "333shop".

How would I be able to call (or even define) the function for this shop named "333shop", since the functionname would have to be `333shop_functionality()`?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what in specific the pre-processing means. Will you have different preprocessing rules for every shop or do some shops share the same preprocessing rules?

Comment: If a shop requires preprocessing, there is a function defined that starts with the shopname. There are no functions shared between shops. (well... of course there are, but not regarding this issue ;) )

Comment: Not a direct answer but could you simply rename the functions to be `shop_[shopidentifier]_functionality` (i.e. `shop_amazon_functionality`)?

Comment: @Jim great idea, why didn't I think of that before :) I still am wondering if there really is no workaround for it :)

Comment: fyi: I ended up using `functionality_[shopidendifier]` instead of [shopidentifier]_functionality . Smallest change :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say there isn't according to the documentation:

> Function names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus: [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this, but was wondering if there would be any way around it :)

Comment: Yes there most likely is a better solution, but your question needs more info